# How to Populate the data from xml to java bean class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to populate all the `xml` data to java bean class,

```
<employee>
    <empId>a01</empId>
    <dptName>dev</dptName>
    <person>
        <name>xyz</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <phone>123456</phone>
    </person>
</employee>
```

Below is the java bean class in which i want to store the `xml` data.

```
class employee{
 private String empId;
 private String dptName;
 private Person person;
    //getter setter below
    }

class Person{
    String name;
    private String age;
    private String phone;
    //getter setter below
}
```

I think this can be done using `JAXB` but how ?

Note : further i have to save the data into data base.

Comment: you can simply parse the xml and extract "node text" and assign to variable by creating their instances (you may further need getter-setters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any annotations you could do the following with [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) which is included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6:

### Without Annotations

Your model appears to match all the default naming rules necessary to map to the XML that you have posted.  This means that you can use your model without adding any metadata in the form of annotations.  One thing to note is that if you don't specify metadata to associate root elements with classes then you need to specify a `Class` parameter when unmarshalling and wrap the root object in an instance of `JAXBElement` when marshalling.

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will convert the XML to objects and then convert the objects back to XML.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<Employee> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Employee.class);
Employee employee = je.getValue();

Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

---

### Removing the Need to `JAXBElement` with `@XmlRootElement`

When a class is associated with a root element using `@XmlRootElement` (or `@XmlElementDecl`) then you don't need to specify the `Class` parameter when unmarshalling or wrap the result in a `JAXBElement` when marshalling.

**Employee**

```
@XmlRootElement
class Employee {
```

**Demo**

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Employee employee = (Employee) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(employee, System.out);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Answer (score -2):

You can do this thing easily with the [xstream api](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

```
XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again.
```

Here you will find documentation [XStream Core 1.4.5-SNAPSHOT documentation](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/)